# How to apply a function to each column of a pivot table in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("example.csv", parse_dates=['ds'])
df2 = df.set_index(['ds', 'city']).unstack('city')
rm = pd.rolling_mean(df2, 3)
sd = pd.rolling_std(df2,3)
```

df2 output:

[image]

What I want: I want to be able to see whether for each city, for each date, if the number is greater than 1 std dev away from the mean of bookings for that city. For ex pseudocode:

```
for each (city column) 
for each (date)
see whether the (number of bookings) - (same date and city rolling mean) > (same date and city std dev)
print that date and city and number of bookings
```

What the problem is: I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to access the data I need from each of the data frames to do so. The parts of the pseudocode in parenthesis is what I need help figuring out.

What I tried:

df2['city']
list(df2)

Both give me errors.

df2[1:2]

Splicing works, but I feel like thats not the best way to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `apply` function of DataFrame API. Demo is below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4,5]; 'B': [1,2,3,4,5]})
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['A']*row['B'], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   A  B   C
0  1  1   1
1  2  2   4
2  3  3   9
3  4  4  16
4  5  5  25
```

More concretely for your case:

1. You have to precompute: "same date and city rolling mean", "same date and city std dev". You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) function for it, it allows to aggregate data by **city** and **date**, after that you can calculate std dev and mean.
2. Put std dev and mean in your table, use dictionary for it: `some_dict = {('city', 'date'):[std_dev, mean], ..}`. For putting data in dataframe use *apply* function.
3. You have all necessary data for running your check by *apply* function.

Comment: Does the standard deviation and the rolling mean need to be appended to the original data frame for this apply to work? I think yes bc this is applying the function by row. If yes, then how can I concatenate rolling mean and std dev? I don't think it's as simple as adding a column because df2 is a stacked table/pivot table.

Comment: Yep, I think you should precompute it.

Comment: Do you know how I can add the the last two columns of rm and std dev and change the bookings title of those two columns to mean and std dev when i add it? Appreciate your help. I think I can figure out lambda function from there on.

Comment: Figured out rename by rm=rm.rename(columns = {'column you want to rename':'what you want to rename it to'}).

Comment: Figured out concat by pd.concat([dfs, you, want, to, concat], axis=1).